# working with classes and instances problem

Tags: parameters, python-3.7

I used python3 and this is the error I get type error: object() takes no error in line the_old_car = (1910, "Ford", "coupe")

looked on stack overflow but most of the programs are very complicated.
researched other sections on the internet and found the same situation

```
class Car(object):
    def _init_(self,year,make,model)
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
    def get_car_name(self):
        real_name = str(self.year) + " " + self.make + " " + self.model 
        return real_name.title()
the_old_car = (1910,"FORD", "coupe")
print(the_old_car.get_car_name()
```

the error object() takes no parameters I do not fully understand the meaning as I am new to python

Comment: `__init__` should have 2 underscores... and then you probably want to create an instance: `the_old_car = Car(1910,"FORD", "coupe")` (note the `Car` in front of the parentheses).

Comment: ... and you're missing a close bracket - you need to close the print statement like this `print(the_old_car.get_car_name())`